# What are the file extensions does Apache solr 6.1 support?

Tags: apache, solr

I try apache solr 6.1 to index my document and extract its contents it accepts .doc extension files but not support the .docx or .ppt extension files. It shows the error like "**Connection to Solr lost Please check the Solr instance.**" what the error actually mean?

Comment: What does the Solr log say? Solr [uses Apache Tika for extracting the content of documents](https://tika.apache.org/1.4/formats.html).

Comment: What does the product documentation tell about the file formats soir 6.1 supports and what do the logs of the running instance tell. Please add detail to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No , you are wrong . Solr accepts .docx and .ppt files too without any doubt . The error you are getting is because of your network connection . The connection is not persisitent enough to perform operations . It has nothing to do with the file extensions .